# WPF contextmenu and ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, contextmenu

Ok, hopefully this is simple but for some reason I can't find a straight answer and I'm not familiar enough with WPF yet to know how to do it.

I have a listview, it gets bound to an observable collection of objects to display. I want to have a context menu with a bunch of options. The options in the context menu are relative to the particular object in the list that was clicked on (things like delete, export, etc).

So I need the object that the user right clicked on in my listview to be passed as a parameter to the command that the context menu executes.

How do I do this?

Edit: I should mention I would prefer a solution that is mostly (if not entirely) xaml - I'm trying to avoid having significant code in the code-behind. If that's the only way to do it though...

**Further Edit**: More details that I forgot to mention that are important. The command I want executed is on the object bound to the data context of my user control, it is not on the objects in the list view. So I need the context menu's on the list view's items to be bound to a command that is on the user control's data context, and the listview item passed as a parameter into that command.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on whether your `ContextMenu` is part of the template for individual items, or if it is attached to the ListBox as a whole.

If you are attaching your `ContextMenu` to the items in the list using a DataTemplate (this is generally the best way to do it), the `DataContext` on the `MenuItem` is already set so all you need to do is:

```
<MenuItem ... CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

On the other hand, if your `ContextMenu` is attached to the `ListBox` as a whole, you'll need to access the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox`:

```
<MenuItem ... CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,ListBox,1}} />
```